# Problem understanding the representation of a cellular automaton using a CNN

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am having problems understanding how the author in "[Cellular automata as convolutional neural networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.02942.pdf)" is representing a CA with a CNN. Specifically in appendix A we have:

[image]

I don't understand two things,

1. How filters of dimension $M$ are applied on a lattice of dimensions $L\times L\times(M+1)$ in the second step and
2. How the result is something useful, i.e. what the $L\times L\times M$ resulting lattice is exactly representing.